# How can i register hours on Oracle's SQL Developer 20.2 for 11g database?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to register a DATE and and hour field on a table. DATE is there, but i can't find the TIME type for the hour field. Is there another way to make the thing? Or am i missing something? I'm trying to register the hour on a '11:30' format.

Comment: What do you mean by "register" something on a table? Do you mean `INSERT`? Do you mean **store** (that is, you are creating the table right now, and you must define the columns and their data types)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `time` datatype in Oracle. There is a `date` datatype, that stores the date *and time*.

You did not explain your actual use case, but: most of the times, you don't need, and don't want, to store the date and times in two separate columns. You can use `date`, that stores both. Then you can use date functions to access the date and time parts separately if you really need to (or use computed columns).

Comment: i see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

An Oracle `date` column always contains a day and a time.  There would generally be no reason to have a separate column to store the time.

```
create table foo (
  my_date_col date
);

insert into foo( my_date_col ) 
  values( to_date( '2020-11-23 11:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi' ) );

select trunc( my_date_col ) date_data_type_at_midnight,
       to_char( my_date_col, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) string_representation_of_day,
       to_char( my_date_col, 'hh24:mi:ss' ) string_representation_of_time
  from foo;
```